# Liferay + Solr + Nutch

Tags: apache, solr, liferay, web-crawler, nutch

Readme: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324162/nutch-and-solr-with-liferay

I am at the exact same point now. I tried to merge the schema files or just changed the uniquekey but nothing worked. Nutch 1.4 and Solr 3.6.1 run fine when using the same schema, the one from nutch. Liferay 6.1.0 solr-web plugin and Solr 3.6.1 also run fine when both use the schema from solr-web.

Have you solved this problem?

Is there an alternative? We also have a Google Search Appliance. Crawling is no problem, but how to integrate into the Liferay search-portlet? Maybe it is possible to use the Liferay Luscene Search + Google Search Appliance?

Answer (score 1):

Liferay search portlet needs uid to be the primary key.
Hence, keep the unique key as uid and then copy unique key of nutch into uid by using copyField